# Unable to Resign UIPickerview from UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uipickerview, uitoolbar

I have a UItable with a UItextbox in it. When the user taps the textbox, the UIPickerView is presented and allows the user to make a choice. There is a toolbar attached to the UIPickerView with a done button. I can not get the done button to resign the UIPickerView.

I have multiple UIPickerViews as this is a requirement. So I placed my toolbar in its own method to reuse it.

The picker delegate methods all work and populate the correct text and update the textbox. I just can't get the picker to dismiss.

in my **viewDidLoad**

```
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];

    self.pickerColor = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    [self.pickerColor setDataSource:self];
    [self.pickerColor setDelegate:self];
    self.pickerColor.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    self.txt_color.delegate = self;
    self.txt_color.inputView = self.pickerColor;
    self.txt_color.inputAccessoryView = [self returnPickerToolbar];
```

There are other pickers (pickerShape, pickerNumber) all with corresponding textboxes.

**The Toolbar**

```
- (UIToolbar*) returnPickerToolbar {
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];


    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(doneData:)];

    [self.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceLeft, doneButton, nil]];
    return self.toolbar;
}
```

**The done button**

```
- (void) doneData : (id) sender {
    UIPickerView * picker = (UIPickerView*)sender;
    [picker resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `resignResponder` of `UITextField` not the `UIPickerView`.
Your picker is the inputView of that textfield, so resigning responder of that textfield will automatically dismiss the picker.

```
- (void)doneData:(id) sender
{
    [self.txt_color resignFirstResponder];
    // Also you can use [self.view endEditing];
}
```

Comment: @Firemarble : Check whether done button event is triggering or not

Answer (score 0):

If UIPickerView is an inputView of UITextField, then you should set your Toolbar as inputAccessoryView of UITextfield. Then all of buttons on toolbar should be enabled.